# Settings from "app.config" is not being gotton in class library project

Tags: c#, app-config, class-library

Problem is that my settings from "app.config" is not being gotten in class library project.

Can "app.config" be used in applications only and not in class libraries?

Comment: They can be used, but in the context of the application, so your application will have an app.config and when your library code looks up settings it will do so in this app.config, not its own one.

Comment: Have you added a reference to `System.Configuration` to your project?

Answer (score 1):

You should add the config settings to the project that is using the class project. ie If you have a project 'MyProject' that references 'MyClassProject' then the app.config settings should be placed in the 'MyProject' project

Answer (score 0):

Application configuration files contain settings specific to an application. This file contains configuration settings that the common language runtime reads (such as assembly binding policy, remoting objects, and so on), and settings that the application can read. The config file is optional, if it does not exist environments such as ASP.NET will fall back to the machine.config file stored in the .NET system directories to get machine wide defaults.

Think about it like that. If you class library has some custom settings then it should have a config to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

By design of .NET framework when you access *Application configuration* with default means - .NET runtime supplies you with data from *app.config* of entry assembly (an EXE file that references your class library).

*Application Configuration* of class library can be accessed in following way (code should be placed in project of class library - in order for `Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location` to return proper path):

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap classLibraryConfigurationMap= new ExeConfigurationFileMap();
classLibraryConfigurationMap.ExeConfigFilename = Assembly.GetCallingAssembly().Location + ".config";

Configuration classLibraryConfiguration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(classLibraryConfigurationMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
```